# Getting the value of a name array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am wanting to store more than one value into option inputs. I searched around and figured out how to do this. However, what I could not find is how I get the value out of the name array. As you can see in the snippet, I have this in a change event and write the value to `#result`. I am wanting to write the value of the `years[]` to `#years`.

How can I get the value of the name array?

[In case you want one, here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/dydskveu/)

```js
$('#tp-frequency').on('change', function () {
  var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected').val();
  $('#result').html(templates);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tp-frequency">
  <option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
  <option class="choice" value='3' name="years[3]">3 years - 3 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='4' name="years[2]">2 years - 4 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='2' name="years[5]">5 years - 2 cards</option>
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="years"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to print `3 years - 3 cards`, ...etc?

Comment: I am wanting to print the value within the name array for the selected option,

Comment: Where is the array `years`???

Comment: Post an example of the desired output!!

Comment: I just posted an answer with what it sounds like you are asking

Comment: What do you mean where is the array years..... right here 'name="years[3]"`'. It is in each input, but different values.

Comment: @Paul still vague! What is the point? Explain!

Comment: I am not sure how else to explain it. I just want to get the data out of the array, based on the option selected. Then print the data that was selected.

Comment: To make it simple ... what does `years[3]` represent to you? What is it for? How is it generated? Why is it set up that way? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Paul question is not clear.

Comment: @charlietfl Why does it matter what `years[]` represents...obviously it is years. I don't know how else to explain this.

Comment: So why not just set the number as attribute value if that is all you want? Doesn't make sense using that syntax if all you want to do is parse out the number

Comment: Paul `years[data]` is a string! That's it!

Comment: @Paul we're asking because we have doubts that the options could be generated in a better way. So the retreiving of the data could be much easier than what you're asking!

Comment: I did it the way I am because I need the value number which is the chosen amount and then I added the name field to get the amount of years for it. Everything I read on here said if you need multiple values to create a name and make it an array.

Comment: @Paul your best bet is to store the years value without the string `years` just pure number!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir so just `name="3"`, `name="5"`, etc? Would I call for it any differant than Nenad's answer?

Comment: @Paul It will be much better.

Comment: @Paul that is only for form control names....`<option>` is not a form control that actually gets submitted `<select>` is

Comment: Yep, no need for regular expressions then. Also you can just use `data-years` custom attribute.

Comment: @Paul check my answer bellow! I explained how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get number that is inside name attr you can use `attr('name')` of selected option and then regular expression to get number.

```js
$('#tp-frequency').on('change', function() {
  $('#result').html($('#tp-frequency option:selected').val());
  $('#years').html($(this).find(':selected').attr('name').match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tp-frequency">
  <option value='' disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
  <option class="choice" value='3' name="years[3]">3 years - 3 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='4' name="years[2]">2 years - 4 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='2' name="years[5]">5 years - 2 cards</option>
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="years"></p>
```

You can also create custom data attribute called `data-years` and then you can get its value using `data("years")`

```js
$('#tp-frequency').on('change', function() {
  $('#result').html($(this).find(':selected').val())
  $('#years').html($(this).find(':selected').data('years'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tp-frequency">
  <option value='' disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
  <option class="choice" value='3' data-years="3">3 years - 3 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='4' data-years="2">2 years - 4 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='2' data-years="5">5 years - 2 cards</option>
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="years"></p>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: How would I do the `data-years` custom attribute?

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware you could do that! I appreciate it. Can you store images in data-attributes as well?

Comment: If you meant image url  then yes.

Comment: Cool. That was something I was wondering how to do. I will work on it and if I cannot get it to work I will create a new question and put the link here in case you wish to look at it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nenard Vracar Does this work different with checkbox inputs?

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that you use the `value` attribute to store cards and the `name` attribute to store years. When generating the option you could easly just use other attributes such as `data-years` and `data-cards` to store the numbers only of those values. to get elements like this:

```
<option class="choice" data-cards='3' data-years="3">3 years - 3 cards</option>
<option class="choice" data-cards='4' data-years="2">2 years - 4 cards</option>
<option class="choice" data-cards='2' data-years="5">5 years - 2 cards</option>
```

using some javascript code like this:

```
var $option = $('<option></option>');
$option.addClass('choice');
$option.attr('data-years', youYearsValueHere);
$option.attr('data-cards', youCardsValueHere);
$option.text(/*...*/);
```

So when you want to get those values you can easly do this:

```
$('#tp-frequency').on('change', function () {
    var $option = $('#tp-frequency option:selected');
    var years = $option.attr('data-years');
    var cards = $option.attr('data-cards');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this is what you want. If not explain further and I will fix the answer.

```js
$('#tp-frequency').on('change', function () {
  var templates = $('#tp-frequency option:selected').attr('name');
  $('#result').html(JSON.parse(templates.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[0]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="tp-frequency">
  <option value=''disabled selected>Please choose option</option>
  <option class="choice" value='3' name="years[3]">3 years - 3 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='4' name="years[2]">2 years - 4 cards</option>
  <option class="choice" value='2' name="years[5]">5 years - 2 cards</option>
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="years"></p>
```

Comment: How do I just the value of the years array... Just the 3,2 or5.

Comment: No, the OP has a `years` array with data in it. They want to access `years[n]` based on which option is selected and put that value in the `#result` element